# C++ many SFINAE-style overloads

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, sfinae

Is it possible to make many overloads/specifications at once many times, like in the code below.
I hope it is clear, what I was trying to achieve, but compiler doesn't think so.

```cpp
#include <stdint.h>

struct IP_address
{
    uint32_t value;
};


template<typename T> struct Unsigned_type {};
template<> struct Unsigned_type<uint8_t >{ typedef uint8_t   type; };
template<> struct Unsigned_type<uint16_t>{ typedef uint16_t  type; };
template<> struct Unsigned_type<uint32_t>{ typedef uint32_t  type; };
template<> struct Unsigned_type<uint64_t>{ typedef uint64_t  type; };

template<typename T> struct Signed_type {};
template<> struct Signed_type<uint8_t >{ typedef uint8_t   type; };
template<> struct Signed_type<uint16_t>{ typedef uint16_t  type; };
template<> struct Signed_type<uint32_t>{ typedef uint32_t  type; };
template<> struct Signed_type<uint64_t>{ typedef uint64_t  type; };

template<typename T> 
T parse(const char*);

template <typename T>
typename Unsigned_type<T>::type parse(const char* str)
{
    return 1;
}

template <typename T>
typename Signed_type<T>::type parse(const char* str)
{
    return -1;
}

template <>
IP_address parse(const char* str)
{
    IP_address result;
    result.value = 0x08080808;
    return result;
}


int main()
{
    uint32_t parsed_uint = parse<uint32_t>("300");
    int32_t parsed_int = parse<int32_t>("-1337");
    IP_address parsed_ip = parse<IP_address>("8.8.8.8");
    uint8_t should_throw = parse<uint8_t>("300");
    return 0;
}
```

Both clang and gcc tell `call to 'parse' is ambiguous`, but I have no idea why, I've explicitly specified the type! Please help me understand why this doesn't compile and how to make it work? By the way is it even possible to not repeat yourself without using macro in this case?

Compilation error, as requested.

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:47:49: error: call of overloaded ‘parse<uint32_t>(const char [4])’ is ambiguous
   47 |     uint32_t parsed_uint = parse<uint32_t>("300");
      |                                                 ^
test.cpp:22:3: note: candidate: ‘T parse(const char*) [with T = unsigned int]’
   22 | T parse(const char*);
      |   ^~~~~
test.cpp:25:33: note: candidate: ‘typename Unsigned_type<T>::type parse(const char*) [with T = unsigned int; typename Unsigned_type<T>::type = unsigned int]’
   25 | typename Unsigned_type<T>::type parse(const char* str)
      |                                 ^~~~~
test.cpp:31:31: note: candidate: ‘typename Signed_type<T>::type parse(const char*) [with T = unsigned int; typename Signed_type<T>::type = unsigned int]’
   31 | typename Signed_type<T>::type parse(const char* str)
      |                               ^~~~~
test.cpp:50:48: error: call of overloaded ‘parse<uint8_t>(const char [4])’ is ambiguous
   50 |     uint8_t should_throw = parse<uint8_t>("300");
      |                                                ^
test.cpp:22:3: note: candidate: ‘T parse(const char*) [with T = unsigned char]’
   22 | T parse(const char*);
      |   ^~~~~
test.cpp:25:33: note: candidate: ‘typename Unsigned_type<T>::type parse(const char*) [with T = unsigned char; typename Unsigned_type<T>::type = unsigned char]’
   25 | typename Unsigned_type<T>::type parse(const char* str)
      |                                 ^~~~~
test.cpp:31:31: note: candidate: ‘typename Signed_type<T>::type parse(const char*) [with T = unsigned char; typename Signed_type<T>::type = unsigned char]’
   31 | typename Signed_type<T>::type parse(const char* str)
      |
```

Comment: Please show the complete code displaying the error. You can use something like godbolt.org or coliru.stacked-crooked.com to provide a reproducible snippet.

Comment: You can't partially specialize function templates. What you have is 3 overloaded functions, and it's ambiguous which one to call.

Comment: @super is it a partiall specialization? There is only one type argument.

Comment: It is kinda strange to me that you use uintXX_t as Signed_type instantiations.

Comment: What is the purpose of this code? There are already `std::is_integral` and `std::is_signed` in the standard library.

Comment: @Jouny It doesn't matter how many type arguments there are. A partial specialization has `template <...>` and a full specialization has `template <>`. The IP_Address one is valid. The other two are not.

Comment: @walnut The purpose is to understand c++ for me

Comment: Also, `Signed_type` and `Unsigned_type` are undistinguishable.

Comment: @YSC please, clarify, I don't understand why

Answer (score 0):

You cannot partially specialize template function. But you can define a class template having a SFINAE call operator:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
struct parse
{
    template<class U = T>
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_signed_v<U>, T> operator()(const char* str)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    template<class U = T>
    std::enable_if_t<!std::is_signed_v<U>, T> operator()(const char* str)
    {
        return 1;
    }
};
```

When `parse<T>` is explicitly specialized, template parameter substitution takes place. If `T` is, e.g. `unsigned`, `std::is_signed_v<T>` would be `false`. This makes the compiler try and specialize `std::enable_if_t<false, T>` which is ill-formed. Thankfully this happens in the scope of SFINAE: this definition is simply ignored, making the unsigned version picked up.

#### A bit of documentation

- [`std::is_signed`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_signed)
- [`std::enable_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if)
- [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae)

#### Demo

Renaming the `parse` class to `parse_impl`, you can define an helper function:

```
template<class T>
auto parse(const char* arg)
{ return parse_impl<T>{}(arg); }
```

[Full program](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/21488a31c3ea9203)

Comment: @user253751 you're right; I'm commenting OP's intent in my opening, not their code.

Comment: Somehow I missed the line `template<typename T> T parse(const char*);` and I thought the original code defined two separate templates.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is an overloading problem more than a templates problem.

Simplifying a lot you have two functions:

```
type1 parse(char *) {...}
type2 parse(char *) {...}
```

So, from this part the call is ambiguous.
You try to fix this ambiguity by explicitly providing the template parameter, but both Signed and Unsigned could be instantiated. (It does not important that you explicitly specialized some of them).

So, you get an ambiguity.

How to fix it:
There are different ways, but I opted out for std::enable_if to discard overloads that are not necessary:

```
template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<!std::is_signed_v<T>>>
typename Unsigned_type<T>::type parse(const char* str)
{
    return 1;
}

template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_signed_v<T>>>
typename Signed_type<T>::type parse(const char* str)
{
    return -1;
}
```

Here you have the complete code (not that more changes are made):
https://godbolt.org/z/esAAR6